# Why we use -o nouuid command while mounting volume in AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mounted-volumes

When I tried to find videos to help me to mount a exciting volume to an new instance. the guy in the video used the command "mount -o nouuid /mounting path". why we use -o nouuid command in this place. I tried without that command it doesn't mount can any one explain

I tried the command "mount /root path" it didn't work
And I tried "mount - o nouuid /root path" it did work why?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Answer (score 0):

babu Anandh - The reason is to Ignore the UUID check.

if it's a UUID conflict issue, then you are left with two options:

1. Either you have to Ignore UUID check
2. Change the UUID of one of the file systems

You can check the UUID by below command:

```
$ blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="ce780dbf-6f70-412d-87dd-61654730a231" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bf0d338c-01"
.......
/dev/nvme1n1: UUID="2ddd89c4-415a-4aee-8431-abecdd8c79b8" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/nvme2n1: UUID="2ddd89c4-415a-4aee-8431-abecdd8c79b8" TYPE="xfs"
```

For more info please refer: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ebs-mount-volume-issues